# In vim, syntax color of terminal and iterm are different

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, iterm2

I'm new in vim setting T__T.

[image: in terminal]

 [image: in iterm2]

left is terminal display.

right is iterm2 display.

how to change the color in terminal to be like in iterm2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your color settings from the preferences in iTerm/Terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some vim colorschemes, including the default, take the terminal's color palette as default color values. However, if you use a colorscheme with full 256 color support, I believe there's a 256 colorscheme for the default as well, the issue disappears.

Here's a photo with desert (non-256) as a colorscheme between iTerm and Terminal:
[image: 1]

And here's a photo with jellybeans (256):
[image: 2]

Comment: I use both setting by default.
Besides using 256 colorscheme, It has no way to solve this problem T___T ???

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to set background color light in both terminal and iterm?

In Vim,
: set background=light

or you can add

set background=light

in your .vimrc

Also, unchecking "Draw bold text in bright colors" might fix the issue.